# revealed himself to be every kind of monster

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "revealed himself to be every kind of monster" as "revealed himself to be a monster imaginable" (no matter what kind of monster you imagine, he would be fit to be). Am I on the right track?

> Alot of men have probably wished for four more years. A little under that time after assuming absolute power, Gaius Caesar was dead, assassinated by the men who were paid to protect him. We more usually know him as Caligula: a man who **revealed himself to be every kind of monster** soon after becoming emperor of Rome.

> [Source](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2020/dec/04/decline-and-fall-what-donald-trump-can-learn-from-the-roman-emperors)

Comment: Yes, you are; but  the original is English, and I'm afraid that your paraphase isn't. You still need an indefinite (such as _any_) to make your paraphrase make sense. Your explanation in parenthesis makes your meaning clear, but _he would fit to be_ doesn't make much sense: _he would fit_, or _he would match it_ would work).

Answer (score 2):

"**Revealed himself to be...**" means that, through actions, he *showed himself* to be something.

"**...every kind of monster**" means that they were '*monstrous*' (wicked or cruel) *in every imaginable way*.